# How to draw the data (from gleReadPixels) onto the default (display) farmebuffer in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0, glreadpixels

Sorry if I am asking something which is already available. So far I could not trace. I read details about FBO and got a fair idea about off-screen buffering. http://mattfife.com/?p=2813 is a nice little article on FBOs. In all the examples, including this one, I don't see details on how to write the data, retrieved through glReadPixels call, onto default display framebuffer. Sorry if I am missing anything silly. I did my due diligence but could not get any example.

Note: I am using OpenGLES 2.0, hence I cannot use calls such as glDrawPixels, etc.

Basically my requirement is to have off-screen buffering. Because I am working on subtitle/captions wherein scrolling of the caption will have to repeat the rendering of lines till those go out of caption-display area.

I got a suggestion to use FBO and bind the texture created to the main default framebuffer.

My actual need is caption/ subtitle (which can be in scrolling mode)
Suppose the first time I had below on display,
This is Line Number - 1
This is Line Number - 2
This is Line Number - 3

After scrolling, then I want to have,
This is Line Number - 2
This is Line Number - 3
This is Line Number - 4

In the second time when I want to render, I will have to update the content in offscreen FBO? That would be re-writing line-2 and line-3 at a new position, removing line-1 and adding line-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a framebuffer with an texture attachment ([see Attaching Images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Attaching_Images)). Note [`glFramebufferTexture2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glFramebufferTexture2D.xhtml) is supported by OpenGL ES 2.0.
The color plane of the framebuffer can be loaded to the CPU by `glReadPixels`, the same way as when you use a [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object). But the rendering is stored in a 2D [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture).
Bind the texture and the default framebuffer and render a screen space quad with the texture on it.

Render a quad (`GL_TRIANLGE_FAN`) with the vertex coordinates (-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1) and use the following simple OpenGL ES 2.0 shader:

Vertex shader

```c
attribute vec2 pos;
varying vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    uv = pos * 0.5 + 0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 uv;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
}
```

Comment: One more question, I hope you could help: While taking content from the fbo/ attached texture, is it possible to take partial data? I felt glBlitFrameBuffer might be useful but it is not supported in OpenGLES 2.0. glScissor maybe?

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar You can "scale" the texture coordinates (`uv`) to a specific region.

Comment: Thanks, @Rabbid76

Maybe I will put the question this way. 
Suppose first time I had,
This is Line Number -1
This is Line Number -2
This is Line Number -3

Then I want to have,
This is Line Number -2
This is Line Number -3
This is Line Number -4

So basically I am trying to have a scrolling presentation. In the second time when I want to render, I will have to update the content in offscreen fbo? That would be re-writing line-2 and line-3 at new position, removing line-1 and adding line-4.

Sorry to make the question a bit lengthy. But that's the ask I have in my work.

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar *" I will have to update the content in offscreen fbo?"* - No. YOu just have to get the proper "line" from the texture. Textures are repeating (`GL_REPEAT`). See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml). You can add an offset to to the texture coordinates. e.g `texture2D(u_texture, uv + vec2(0.0, 0.5))`. Please note, the comment section is not intended to ask questions. Probably a moderator will delete all this commnts.

Comment: Yeah true. I will put it in a separate question post.

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76 for the texture, from the offscreen fbo, binding to default framebuffer. This worked. Continuing this I tried to render few texts (using freetype lib and then converting to texture using glTexImage2D). But this seems not working. When I try to render directly onto default framebuffer, it works. Probably textures (fonts) rendering onto the fbo's texture attachment is something not possible or needs to be done differently?

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar No, it is not different.

Comment: OK. I will try to debug then. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, I am still trying to debug. Meanwhile, I posted it as a question. It would be great if you can have a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475832/font-rendering-onto-off-screen-fbo-not-working-note-fonts-are-loaded-by-creat

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, can glFramebufferTexture2D be used directly on default framebuffer object 0 as well?

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar No. You cannot attach a buffer to the default framebuffer. The default framebuffer is the buffer that is associated to the window, it can't be _changed_ or _suited_ by the application after the context is established. It is just possible to specify the format of the default framebuffer (restricted to the hardware).

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, that helps. I was thinking of creating a texture directly on default framebuffer.
Is it possible to attach multiple textures to the same framebuffer object? Like attaching-1 then drawing a few things and then attaching-2 and drawing a few other things. And on default framebuffer I would draw both the attached textures.

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76, as the last asked one is a separate question altogether. I posted a separate one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654976/attaching-multiple-textures-to-single-fbo-andmultiple-fbos-in-opengl-es-2-0
Could you please help!